# How to use a Google map event listener to pass a variable and submit a form

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I'm following a Google Maps v3 demo gallery example [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rectangle-overlay/rectangle-overlay.html), which is a rectangle overlay.  I modified the rectangle to make it clickable.

```
rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
   map: map,
   clickable: true
});
```

Then I added an event listener to the rectangle

```
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', editSite);
```

and made a method to cause the form to submit, and it worked properly.

```
function editSite() {
    document.getElementById("siteSelection").value = 22;
    document.siteSelectionForm.submit();
}
```

Next, I changed editSite's signature by adding an argument.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', editSite(22));
```

...

```
function editSite(siteId) {
    document.getElementById("siteSelection").value = siteId;
    document.siteSelectionForm.submit();
}
```

It stopped working properly.  The form would submit as soon as the map loaded, which was before I ever had the opportunity to click the rectangle.  It's as though the method was invoked as soon as it was added to the listener during page reload.

My goal is to be able to create many rectangles, each rectangle, when clicked, passing a unique ID to editSite.  How can I do this and avoid the problem I've created?

Comment: i can say 3 things; 1. you forgot to close the bracket here: google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', editSite(22); 2. That is not how you send in parameters; and 3. You make the listener go to editSite but post code for assignSite. Apart from point 2, i guess you probably mistyped while crunching the actual code to post here

Comment: Good catches. I did a lot of translating, copying/pasting for the example.  I'll go ahead and clean up the code for the benefit of others.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok changes have been made, typos fixed. - pg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't do what you expect (and it is missing a closing ")", is that a typo?):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', editSite(22);
```

the "editSite" without the arguments is a function pointer (in your "working" code):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', editSite);
```

if you add an argument, it gets executed immediately and the return value is used as the function to be executed when the event occurs (not what you want in this case).  If you want to call a named function with an argument, wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', function() {
  editSite(22);
});
```