# How to use this in google.maps.event.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The following example works, but when I try to pass a parameter and use `this` in the function does not work.

Working:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', showInfoWindow);

      function showInfoWindow() {

          var service_marker = this;
          service.getDetails({placeId: service_marker.placeResult.place_id},
          function(place, status) {
            if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              return;
            }

          });
        }
```

When I try to pass a parameter `service_obj` with the following code. It does not work and the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'place_id' of undefined` is displayed.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', showInfoWindow(service_obj));

      function showInfoWindow(service_obj) {

          var service_marker = this;
          service.getDetails({placeId: service_marker.placeResult.place_id}, //error here
          function(place, status) {
            if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              return;
            }

          });
        }
```

I believe `this` is not refering to the instance `markers[i]` anymore. I am fairly new to this so sorry about the terminology mistakes. If anyone could help me out or lead me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map addDomListener function parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791921/google-map-adddomlistener-function-parameter)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a Google map event listener to pass a variable and submit a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273986/how-to-use-a-google-map-event-listener-to-pass-a-variable-and-submit-a-form/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does “google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960231/what-does-google-maps-event-adddomlistenerwindow-load-initialize-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When  you pass an argument to the function in the third argument, the function is executed immediately (which is why `this` isn't what you expect) and the return value is used as the event handler function.  You can use an anonymous function to allow you to call a function with parameters:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (evt) { // the click event function is called with the "event" as an argument
    showInfoWindow(evt, this, service, map, infowindow);
});

function showInfoWindow(evt, service_marker, service, map, infowindow) {
  service.getDetails({
      placeId: service_marker.placeResult.place_id
    }, 
    function (place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, service_marker);
      } else {
        infowindow.setContent("error: "+status);
        infowindow.open(map,service_marker);
      }
    });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s018Lbu2/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [];
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.nearbySearch({
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 50000,
    keyword: "restaurant"
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var marker = createMarker(results[i], service, map, infowindow);
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(place, service, map, infowindow) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  marker.placeResult = place;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) { // the click event function is called with the "event" as an argument
    showInfoWindow(evt, this, service, map, infowindow);
  });
  return marker;
}

function showInfoWindow(evt, service_marker, service, map, infowindow) {
  service.getDetails({
      placeId: service_marker.placeResult.place_id
    }, //error here
    function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, service_marker);
      } else {
        infowindow.setContent("error: " + status);
        infowindow.open(map, service_marker);
      }

    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks geocodezip this is correct. Sorry for the duplicated question.

Comment: I just tried and `this` is still referring to the window and not `markers[i]`. I tried passing `markers[i]` as an argument, but it always comes out as `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue as suggested in [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry. I figured it out though. I didn't need to use `this`. I had to add `var self = markers[i];` above my event listener. Then pass it as a parameter when calling my function. `showInfoWindow(self, service_obj);`.